How may I manually construct CAN message for CANopen?
I understand CANopen uses CAN, the difference is usage and message type. I have basic CAN capable device and I want to control industrial motor controller, which uses CANopen.
I have its EDS file, but my knowledge ends here. I have experience with CAN devices (automotive use). I always would use CAN ID and the data bytes. How CANopen would be used?
These are few lines from EDS file:
[406B]
ParameterName=Torque monitor
ObjectType=0x7
DataType=0x0003
AccessType=ro
PDOMapping=1

I think the 406B would be CAN ID?
Here's info from CANopen datasheet for the controller:

So read-only would indicate its the information transmitted from controller. Of course, I would also need to somehow request this info. So my question is - how do I construct messages and how do I request messages?
Also, here's another screenshot from datasheet:

This makes me believe there's much more than just DATA bytes going. Also datasheet gives me no info on how to CRC the data.

Reading the headline made me think about whistling bits instead of using a modem.

A lot is going to depend on what CAN MAC you are using, and the software API for it.

@Smith What's "CAN MAC", is it some PLC term?

This is a good question which unfortunately cannot be answered in the stackexchange format restrictions. See for example this very good discussion on PDO messaging. And it is just a fraction of the over-engineered and bloated monster that is CANopen.

@Lundin It's my pet term for the CAN controller, to distinguish it from the transceiver (i.e., PHY).  I'm basically borrowing Ethernet-type terms to apply to CAN.  I mention it because the OP doesn't mention how they are interacting with the CAN controller, nor what API is involved therein.

@Smith I think that's just confusing since CAN is nothing like Ethernet, they are different in almost every imaginable way.

@Lundin Not really, they both report to parts of standard OSI layers.  I've spent enough time trying to get software engineers, who are used to Ethernet, to understand CAN, and they respond better when you explain that the CAN transceiver is analogous to the PHY layer, and the CAN controller is analogous to the MAC layer, and their software stacks, J1939 or CANopen or what have you, are above that.

@Smith Then why not refer to layers of the OSI model rather than of Ethernet. Engineers know the OSI model since that's mandatory study in both computer engineering and electrical engineering. But engineers do not necessarily know Ethernet and/or CAN.

@Lundin Yes and that was my point: teaching a software engineer steeped in Ethernet about CAN can be aided by adjusting the terms to what they are familiar with.

You need all the prerequisite knowledge first. Learn things in order: basic data communication including the OSI model then CAN then CANopen. Don't skip directly to CANopen when you don't know the prerequisites.

I understand CANopen uses CAN, the difference is usage and message type.

That doesn't make any sense: it's like saying that the difference between a car and a car engine is usage. Eh? CANopen is the application tier, CAN is the hardware and datalink layers. Although CANopen does specify some parts of the lower layers too, such as recommended connectors & pinouts, LED diagnostic behavior etc.
CANopen is a whole application-tier with several different protocols. It is pretty complex and how to use it depends on if you need it to be a clean product conforming to the CANopen standard, or some quick & dirty thing which just uses a minimal subset of CANopen. In case of the latter, this might be sufficient as non-conforming bare minimum.

I think the 406B would be CAN ID?

No. The EDS file is a description of all messages supported by a specific node, and where they are located in the Object Dictionary. The Object Dictionary being a virtual memory map of sorts where CAN behavior of a node can be changed from other nodes. It uses hex notation and 406B would be the address in the Object Dictionary where you can find the particular object. As you can for example here, 0x4000 is inside the manufacturer-specific area so it's some custom location.
Now it doesn't really matter so much where the particular object you are interested in is located. What matters is how it is mapped into an actual data frame, a PDO. You will have to dig up the PDO mapping parameters elsewhere in the Object Dictionary to tell if/how this particular item is mapped to a PDO. If not, you might have to map it yourself (dynamic PDO mapping).

So read-only would indicate its the information transmitted from controller.

No. It means that it is read-only object in the Object Dictionary.
And well, if you didn't get the hint already, this is quite complex. You can't really hope to use neither CAN nor CANopen without studying. The first place to stop at is the official site CAN in Automation where you can also download the CANopen standards (for free, though registration might be necessary).

So my question is - how do I construct messages and how do I request messages?

You don't, you use the existing PDOs after having configured them. There are receive PDOs and transmit PDOs. Which can be sent in a number of ways: cyclically, as per reception of a SYNC message, as per an inhibit timer, as per RTR request in the CAN frame etc etc.
Now there is also something in CANopen called "device profiles", which are standard templates for certain types of applications, like "general I/O module" or "drives and motion control" etc etc. It may be that your particular device belongs to a device profile, after which it's behavior, messages and mapping etc is according to that device profile.

Also, here's another screenshot from datasheet

That just describes how a CAN frame works on the data link layer. That's basic stuff not related to CANopen as such. As I mentioned at the top, the basics of CAN hardware and data link layers are prerequisite knowledge before moving on to CANopen.

Also datasheet gives me no info on how to CRC the data.

Because it is handled by the CAN controller and we need not worry our pretty heads about it.

"You don't, you use the existing PDOs after having configured them." Technically, if OP is not using commercial CANopen stack, they do need to construct and parse messages. So the question is legit. Unfortunately you are correct in that the answer to it will take pages and still may be misunderstood without prerequisite knowledge.

It's completely unnecessary to configure and use PDOs, unless streaming unsolicited data is required.  SDO will work just fine for reading and writing values in the object dictionary.

Since yesterday I did digging into the datasheet, I think I understand, that CANopen frames can be used with regular CAN network. https://canlogger1000.csselectronics.com/img/intel/canopen/CANopen-COB-ID-Message-Format-CAN-Frame_2.png - this explains how CAN message is constructed, and that I would need to integrate various things like function code, node ID, which would essentially then represent regular CAN ID. But this website does not explain how and if CRC is needed. Also there is that SOM, ACK and EOM in my attached screenshot, which I did not find info about.

@Maple Still you may only use the PDOs that are registered and supported by the node.

@BenVoigt See comments below the linked answer. Particularly: "SDO communication should only happen in pre-operational mode though. A control system which allows its outputs to be affected while in pre-operational mode is of questionable design. Also, SDO communication would also require slightly more overhead data traffic, expedited or not."

@RiDi As written multiple times in this answer, you need to study how basic CAN works before anything else. You still seem to be under the impression that you are supposed to manually "bit bang" CAN frames. No sane person will do that - leave it to the CAN controller. It takes care of everything in the CAN frame format - you only need to worry about identifier, data, DLC and RTR.

@Lundin: Do you have a citation for SDOs being unavailable in Operational state?  I see only a restriction on PDOs (they are not available Pre-operational)

@BenVoigt It is simply how you design mission critical real-time systems. You have a safe mode and an operational mode. SDOs do not typically have real-time performance since they come in various variable flavours. And so they shouldn't be present in a situation where real-time matters. That's the main reason but there are various minor things too, such as that we aren't allowed to change any COBID in operational mode.

@Lundin: And yet, embedded systems often use request/response protocols as well as scheduled unsolicited transfers.  Yes there are Pre-operational (SDO supported, no PDO) and Operational (both SDO and PDO supported) states, but that's not an argument that excludes SDOs in any way.  Real-time systems almost always have a subset of data that needs to be transferred promptly but without a hard real-time constraint (for example, reading calibration history); SDO is good for that.

@BenVoigt The problem is that SDOs do not necessarily have a higher COBID than the PDOs. So your calibration history stuff might decide to take precedence over hard real-time motion control commands in the bus arbitration. Though I might be biased since I more or less exclusively work with critical stuff like mobile hydraulics. Whereas in some automation line installation, sending SDOs in operational mode might be no big deal. ->

But the conventional CANopen installation tends to work like: some "master" like a PLC sends out SDOs at boot-up configuring all other nodes. After that it then also acts as NMT master sending remote node activation messages, putting all other nodes in operational mode. And then it is pure PDO traffic from there unless some error happens.

@Lundin: Yes, SDO transfers do have a higher COB-ID than any PDO transfer.
